# Sharepoint 2010 - "Tags and Notes" not active

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have installed and configured SharePoint 2010 and am now testing using it.
I can't seem to add a tag to anything. I can choose a specific item (such as a task), but the "Tags and Notes" button is disabled. When I hover over the button, it says I may need permissions in order to tag an item, but I'm the site admin, so I doubt that is the problem. Is there a setting that I need to enable, that will allow tagging?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this issue before, but do you have the Managed Metadata Service configured?

Answer (score 0):

The Managed Metadata Service is scoped at the Farm level, so it can span across multiple Site Collections. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424403.aspx for an overview

1) In any event, to create a new service, go to **Central Administration**, then click Site Settings.

2) Click **Application Management** on the left nav.

3) Under the Service Applications header, click **Manage service applications**.

4) Under the Service Applications tab on the ribbon, within the Create family, choose **New -> Managed Metadata Service** to create a service application on the same farm or, if you have a Metadata service app hosted elsewhere, choose **Connect -> Managed Metadata Service Connection**

Hope this helps a little bit.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I just needed to activate the managed metadata service.